# obj-c to c# hex-to-byte conversion

Tags: c#, objective-c, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Are these equivalent?

Obj-C:

```
[commands appendBytes:"\x1b\x1d\x61\x01"
length:sizeof("\x1b\x1d\x61\x01") - 1];
```

C#:

```
NSMutableData commands = new NSMutableData ();
commands.AppendBytes (new byte[] {0x1b, 0x1d, 0x61, 0x01});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, yes. These two are equivalent.